# Running long running linux command on screen session

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have written a bash script, it includes a portion where the script checks the file size and if it exceeds 2GB then it will start a screen session and starts importing the DB dump file. But when the script execution reaches that specific part, it's not working. Means, the script is finishing execution before the db dump gets imported. I'm guessing that it's happening because the screen session is not waiting for the db dump import command execution to be completed. Script won't look that professional as I'm a beginner in shell scripting and I'm not that good at coding too, please don't mind.

**Note:** I have created a screen session with socket number 24602 and I'm trying to execute the db dump import command in that session

**SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /case_data
echo "Conditions:
        1.DB dump file should be there in /case_data/<case number>/ location
        2.DB dump file should end with extension .sql"

        read -p "Please enter a case number for which you need to update the DB file:" casenum


if [[ -z "$casenum" ]] ; then
        echo 'Exiting automation as there is no user INPUT. Hasta La Vista!!'
        return 0

elif [[ ${#casenum} -ne 5 ]]; then
        echo "Error: Case number should contain 5 characters. Please enter the case number again!!"
        return 0

elif [[ $casenum == *['!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]* ]]; then
        echo "Error: Special characters are not allowed. Please enter the case number again!!"
        return 0

elif [ -e "$casenum" ]; then

        echo "Modifying the DB dump file for the case number $casenum"
        cd /case_data/$casenum
        filesize=`du -h --block-size=G *.sql | head -c 1`
       `sed -i '1s/^/SET autocommit=0;\n/' *.sql`
       `echo "COMMIT;" >> *.sql`
        mv *.sql c$casenum.sql
        echo "DB dump file modification completed!!"
        echo "Initiating customer DB dump import to the DB c$casenum"
if [ $filesize -ge 2 ]; then
        echo "Customer DB greater than 2 GB, started a screen session"
        echo "Customer DB import started. Please wait till the import is completed"
        screen -S 24602 -X 'mysql -ss -N -uroot -ppassword -e "use c$casenum;source /case_data/$casenum/c$casenum.sql";'

else
        echo "Customer DB less than 2 GB so skipping screen session!!!"
        echo "Customer DB import started. Please wait till the import is completed"
        mysql -ss -N -uroot -ppassword -e "use c$casenum;source /case_data/$casenum/c$casenum.sql;"
        echo "Customer DB import completed successfully!!!"
fi

else

        echo "Directory does not exist, please check the case number entered"

fi
```

Comment: What do you see if you enter the command in a command prompt?

Comment: It won't show anything, and I changed the mysql command for  for db creation and db drop of small databases as it requires only short time for execution and it works well. DB import is a long duration process, I believe that's the reason why the script is not getting executed properly as the screen session will get terminated as soon as the command gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood '`screen -X`'.

> -X   Send **the specified command** to a running screen session.

The **specified command** here means a **screen command**, which is a command used in screen's **command line mode** ( C-a : ) or in **screenrc** files.

`screen -S 24602 -X 'mysql ...'` **won't work because `mysql` is a bash external command, NOT a screen command.**

**Replace it with `screen -S 24602 -X screen mysql ...` should work. (NOTE: no quotes.) It will run `mysql ...` in a new window in session 24602, you can hit C-a_C-a to switch window.**

And BTW, `screen -S 24602` doesn't means 'socket number 24602', it means session name is 24602.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion, let me try this and get back to you :-)

Comment: I have tried with below command, but it's not working. A screen session is getting created but db import is not happening. I tried logging in to MySQl and executed show processlist; for confirming.

screen -S 24602 -X screen mysql -ss -N -uroot -ppassword -e "use c$casenum;source /case_data/$casenum/c$casenum.sql";

Comment: Also, my requirement is that, the db dump import should happen in a separate screen window and once the import is complete, it should terminate the screen session and the rest of my script should get executed in the same bash shell and at the end it should display "Customer DB import completed successfully" that part i missed to include in the script. Sorry about that.